# android scrollview thumbnail size

Tags: android, scrollview

I am using scrollview and trying to set thumbnail for the scorllview.
As the size of thumbnail is little large thus it is not showing up properly.
I have tried to set the size of scrollbar but results are still the same.

Comment: You really need to add some more information: what does your current code and/or layout look like? Also, define "not showing up properly"; e.g. what should it look like and what does it currently look like?

Comment: I think you also need to clarify what a "scrollview thumbnail" is. And what does the scrollbar have to do with anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I said "not showing up properly" I mean to say that the scrollview size attribute is (i.e android:scrollbarSize="15px" ) not coming into effect, and it using some default vaule thus thumbnail is shrinking.

Anyways I have found the soulution to it.There is a bug in scrollview.
android:scrollbarSize attribute come into effect only when we use both 
(android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/thumb01" and android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@drawable/thumb01") attributes otherwise the android:scrollbarSize attribute value doesn't comes into effect.

for more info refer the following url
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14317

Sorry for the ambiguous question.